# How to set non copyable captured variable from inside a lambda

Tags: c++

I'm trying to set a non copyable variable from inside a lambda. Of course the lambda could return a reference to this variable, but let's suppose it can't:

```
#include <optional>
#include <functional>

class NonCopyable {
public:
  NonCopyable() = default;
  NonCopyable(const NonCopyable &) = delete;
  NonCopyable(NonCopyable &&) = default;
};

void do_something_inside_lambda(std::function<void()> f) {
    f();
}

int main() {

    NonCopyable n;
    do_something_inside_lambda([&n](){
        n = NonCopyable();//error
    });
   
}
```

How can I do that without using raw pointers? That is, in a safe way. I tried this too:

```
std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<NonCopyable>> n;
do_something_inside_lambda([&n](){
    n = std::ref(NonCopyable());
});
```

but it won't work.

Comment: Just use `std::optional`? Like `std::optional<NonCopyable> n;` and `n = NonCopyable();`.

Comment: You could wrap it in a `unique_ptr`. That's strictly better than raw pointers. But as long as you've deleted the assignment operator, you won't be able to assign to it. That's what the assignment operator does.

Comment: @songyuanyao this does not work because I also have no assignment. I forgot to add this to the example

Comment: @Rafaelo Oh, you can use `n.emplace();` instead, to  avoid assignment.

Comment: It has nothing to do with a lambda. It's just because it's neither copy-constructible nor copy-assignable.

Comment: @songyuanyao emplace did the trick

Answer (score 0):

`NonCopyable` is still movable, so you should be able to write something like this inside the lambda:

```
NonCopyable n2;
n = std::move(n2);
```